# build a string in javascript using single quotes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, string, razor

Hi I want to build a string in javascript. I am sure I am missing something here. I have been trying from long time

```
'@StringUtils.FormatStringParameter(ValidationMessages.ContractDeleteBudgetValidation,'+ data + ')'
```

Data is a variable that i want to pass. FormatStringParameter is a utility class i have in C#. I want to use that utility class in javascript.

```
  public static string FormatStringParameter(string strng, params object[] listParameters)
    {
        return String.Format(strng, listParameters);
    }

  public const string ContractDeleteBudgetValidation = "Contract has been budgeted. Are you sure you want to {0} ?";
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I am not sure what wrong with this too, but it is not taking, it is saying + unexpected

Comment: We need more context to be able to help you. Why is there a ',' at the end?

Comment: And what is `@StringUtils.FormatStringParameter`? I think you're missing an important tag, and you have a tag (`javascript`) that shouldn't be there -- this isn't a JavaScript question.

Comment: data is the string variable i want to pass as parameter to FormatStringParameter method

Comment: C# string or javascript string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c#, when you use single quotes to wrap around a char, it will try to create an object of `System.Char`. But when you do that you should always pass a single character. In your example, you are passing more than one char(`'+ data + '`). So you are going 
to get an error **"Too many characters in character literal"**

If `data` is a c# variable, you should be calling it like this

```
var yourJsVariable = '@StringUtils.FormatStringParameter(
                         ValidationMessages.ContractDeleteBudgetValidation, data )';
alert(yourJsVariable);
```

Comment: In javascript this works `@StringUtils.FormatStringParameter(ValidationMessages.ConfirmMessage,"XYZ")` but i want to send string variable in place of "xyz". can you please check how to do this in javascript. This is killing me

Comment: Yes, That will also work. You are passing a string instead of using a variable which holds a string value.

Comment: that string variable is a javascript variable :(

Comment: you cannot pass a js variable to c# code because your c# method executes in server even before your  client code executes. It looks like you are simply appending strings. Why not do directly in your js code ?

Comment: That makes sense. I will do that. Thanks a lot.